# Cinemachine Virtual Camera Transition between objects while keeping dead zone

Tags: unity-game-engine, cinemachine

- 3d game
- 2 game objects: A and B. (both spawned on runtime)

I want to get a smooth transition from object A to B, but only if, the object B is outside vcam's dead zone.
Vcam should look at the object with static rotation. (only the camera position should change)

I assume that I have to use:

```
Follow property - because it only affects vcam transform
Framing Transposer - to use dead zones in body component
```

I've tried spawning new vcam with B and disabled the first vcam - this gives smooth transition between cameras, but it does it always, even if A and B are inside dead zones of 1st and 2nd vcam.

How can I achieve smooth camera transition between 2 game objects only if the new one is outside the dead zone of previous vcam?

I know that I can do it by moving object followed by vcam from A to B and this should work with dead zones, but I'm looking for cleaner solution if it's possible

Comment: did you try the follow property of the virtual camera, it seems not linked to the actual unity camera

Comment: Yes, I've tried. Follow with transposer and follow with framing transposer, but with no luck. (Same as 2nd scenario)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Description how to achieve what I described in a question is provided by Unity staff member -  Gregoryl.

CM doesn't give you a notification when things go in and out of dead zones.

You can accomplish what you're looking for by polling the position of B relative to the camera and manually calculating whether the angle between CameraPosToB and CameraForward is sufficiently large, and activating the second vcam when it is.

Here is a part of code - doing what he described:

```
var angleToPlayer = Vector3.Angle(mainCamera.transform.forward, (player.transform.position - mainCamera.transform.position).normalized);
if (angleToPlayer > 20f)
{
    cameraWatchingPlayer.enabled = false;
    Destroy(cameraWatchingPlayer.gameObject, 3f);

    InstantiateCamera(posX, posZ, player.transform);
}
```